# "cassandra.service" fails when I try to create a "systemd" service for it

Tags: ubuntu, service, cassandra, systemd

I am trying to create a `systemd` `cassandra.service`. I have downloaded binary codes and installed it on `Ubuntu 22.04` within `home/a/dons/cassandra` directory. Then tried to create the following file `/etc/systemd/system/cassandra.service` that I founded on the internet :

```
[Unit]
Description=Cassandra Cluster Node Daemon

[Service]
Type=forking
User=cassandra
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/echo "Starting Cassandra Daemon"
ExecStart=/home/a/dons/cassandra/bin/cassandra
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/echo "Cassandra Daemon Running"

ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/rm -rf /data/cassandra/saved_caches;/usr/bin/echo "Cassandra Daemon Stopped"

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Then I tried `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and after that I tried `sudo systemctl status cassandra` but the result is:

```
× cassandra.service - Cassandra Cluster Node Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/cassandra.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-12-20 18:55:41 PST; 1min 17s ago
    Process: 477388 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/echo Starting Cassandra Daemon (code=exited, status=217/USER)
    Process: 477389 ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/rm -rf /data/cassandra/saved_caches;/usr/bin/echo Cassandra Daemon Stopped (code=exited,>
        CPU: 4ms

Dec 20 18:55:41 a systemd[1]: Starting Cassandra Cluster Node Daemon...
Dec 20 18:55:41 a systemd[477388]: cassandra.service: Failed to determine user credentials: No such process
Dec 20 18:55:41 a systemd[477388]: cassandra.service: Failed at step USER spawning /usr/bin/echo: No such process
Dec 20 18:55:41 a systemd[1]: cassandra.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=217/USER
Dec 20 18:55:41 a systemd[1]: cassandra.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=217/USER
Dec 20 18:55:41 a systemd[1]: cassandra.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 20 18:55:41 a systemd[1]: Failed to start Cassandra Cluster Node Daemon.
```

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) Questions about systemd are specifically off topic (see the tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is user `cassandra` probably doesn't exist on your system.

---

Here's a simple example showing the same result on my machine (where user `noexist` doesn't exist):

```
$ systemctl cat simple.service
# /etc/systemd/system/simple.service
[Service]
User=noexist
ExecStart=/bin/true

$ sudo systemctl start simple.service
$ sudo systemctl status simple.service
× simple.service - A simple service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/simple.service; static)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-12-21 09:41:08 CET; 5s ago
   Duration: 413us
    Process: 3314 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=217/USER)
   Main PID: 3314 (code=exited, status=217/USER)
        CPU: 0

Dec 21 09:41:08 systemd[1]: Started simple.service.
Dec 21 09:41:08 systemd[1]: simple.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=217/USER
Dec 21 09:41:08 systemd[1]: simple.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The important part here is the `status=217/USER`.  [`man systemd.exec`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Process%20Exit%20Codes) says:

| Exit Code | Symbolic Name | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 217 | EXIT_USER | Failed to determine or change user credentials, or to set up user namespacing. See User=/PrivateUsers= above. |

---

I think the issue is related to your installation.  Usually you don't install packages to `/home`.  Who owns `/home/a/dons/cassandra`?  This is probably the user that you should run this as.  I would often guess it is user `a`, but on shared systemd with lots of mounts, it might be user `dons`.

I would normally install packages via a package manager (i.e. `apt install`).  This contains scripts which will set up any required users for you, and set up your services.

I did a quick search and found that a `.deb` package does exist for cassandra:

https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/getting_started/installing.html#installing-the-debian-packages

---

If no package was available, I would often try to make a package out of it.  The advantage of a package is that it makes it easier to uninstall or upgrade your software.  This is pretty intense and is beyond the scope of this answer.

---

If you don't want to make a package, you could

1. build from source and `sudo make install DESTDIR=/usr/local`.  This will link to dependencies on your machine already.  It sounds like you want to use pre-compiled binaries (those probably won't work against the exact versions of the dependencies you have installed).
2. Install pre-compiled binaries to `/opt/cassandra`.  Opt is appropriate for add-on, relocatable applications that can't be merged with your main package.

You sound like you want to go with `(2)` and just install binaries without compiling for your system.

Once the binaries/config files are in place, they should be owned by `root` and world readable/executable.  This means any user can run the software, but only `root` can change it.  This prevents `cassandra` from replacing itself with something malicious.

However `cassandra` may need to write somewhere.  You'll have to figure out what directories it needs.  It might be relative to the binary, or could be relative to a working directory, or could be an absolute path.  Given the opportunity, I would probably point this to `/var/lib/cassandra`, but `/opt/cassandra/var` is reasonable too.  Make sure that directory exists.

Next, create system user `cassandra` so you don't need to run this as your primary user, or as root.

```
sudo adduser --system cassandra
```

Now make sure `cassandra` has write access to the data directory:

```
sudo chown -R cassandra /opt/cassandra/var
```

If you're having troubles defining where any var directories should exist, then I strongly recommend installing the `*.deb` package.  All of that is already done for you in the deb package.